# Render new react component on button click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am a newbie to react. I have been trying to render new component. I have two files consisting of two different components.
Fmueditor.js and Viewfmu.js.
Want to use the click event on VIEW button in Fmueditor.js to render Viewfmu.js component.
Kindly help me figure what I am doing wrong.

```
import Viewfmu from './Viewfmu'
class Fmueditor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            message: 'FMU List'
        }
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
    <ButtonToolbar>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick ={this._onButtonClick} >VIEW</Button>
    <Button variant="primary">ASSIGN</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
                <ListGroup>
  <ListGroup.Item>FMU1</ListGroup.Item>
  <ListGroup.Item variant="primary">FMU2</ListGroup.Item>
  <ListGroup.Item action variant="secondary">FMU3</ListGroup.Item>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Fmueditor
```

Viewfmu.js

```
class Viewfmu extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showComponent: false,
        };
        this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this);
    }
    _onButtonClick() {
        this.setState({
          showComponent: true,
        });
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
  <Table striped bordered hover>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
</Table>         
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Viewfmu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply show/hide component by managing the `state` variable.

use `showViewfmu` state variable.

```
this.state = {
    message: 'FMU List',
    showViewfmu: false
}
```

Handle `state` on button click

```
_onButtonClick(){
    this.setState({showViewfmu: !this.state.showViewfmu});
}
```

Add below code to show/hide component

```
{this.state.showViewfmu && <Viewfmu />}
```

Your full code should be look like this...

```
import Viewfmu from './Viewfmu'
class Fmueditor extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            message: 'FMU List',
            showViewfmu: false
        }
    }

    _onButtonClick(){
        this.setState({showViewfmu: !this.state.showViewfmu});
    }

    render() {

        return (
         <div>
          <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={this._onButtonClick} >VIEW</Button>
            <Button variant="primary">ASSIGN</Button>
          </ButtonToolbar>
          <ListGroup>
            <ListGroup.Item>FMU1</ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item variant="primary">FMU2</ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item action variant="secondary">FMU3</ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
          {this.state.showViewfmu && <Viewfmu />}
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Fmueditor
```

In alternative way you can define `routes` and based on the `routes` you can load the component.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
_onButtonClick

Comment: I changed the function call for _onButtonClick() to arrow function and it works. Thanks alot! But, I wanted to hide my FmuEditor component when Viewfmu renders. Can you help with that?

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined _onButtonClick` You can add `this._onButtonClick = this._onButtonClick.bind(this)` in constructor as well to fixed the error. And if you want to show hide your component then you have to put both component in parent component and then handle `state` variable over there.